# Migrated project from 2018.1.6f1 to 2019.2.1f1. Android app crashes after unity splash screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, 2d-games

I have a small game with 3 scenes. I created this game a year ago. And now I migrated it from `2018.1.6f1` to `2019.2.1f1`. 
The app runs smoothly in Unity. But when I create .apk and install it on a real device, it crashes just after the splash screen.

I am sure it's something related to migration because it works perfectly when built with the older version.

I posted same [question](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1661556/android-app-crashes-after-unity-splash-screen-migr.html?sort=votes) on UnityForum. But got no response yet. Hoping to get some solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your device to PC via cabel, open android monitor (is included in Android studio) and then try to run your .apk. Inspect logs in monitor to detect problem or post this logs here.